# Semaphore: understanding initial and maximum number of requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I'm learning c# semaphore and don't understand one point. I can initialize Semaphore like this:

```
var semaphore = new Semaphore(4, 6);
```

There is such explanation in many places:

> If you want to reserve some slots for the calling thread, you can do
>   so by making the first parameter smaller than the second.

Does it mean that only main thread can use remaining 2 resource slots? Does it mean that if I write like this:

```
var semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 6);
```

only main thread can use all 6 slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike lock (Monitor) and Mutex, **Semaphore has no “owner”** — it’s thread-agnostic. Any thread can call Release on a Semaphore, whereas with Mutex and lock, only the thread that obtained the lock can release it.

> Initial value can be used to initiate number of requests for the semaphore that can be granted concurrently. it sets your currently available concurrency level for related sempahore.
>
> While maximum count sets maximum number of requests for the semaphore that can be granted concurrently. it sets your maximum potential concurrency for related semaphore.

You can't increment the counter `CurrentCount` greater than maximum count which you set in initialization.

Following sample shows how Semaphores are Thread agnostic:

```
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, 6);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //semaphore.Release(); //openning another slot for concurreny

        semaphore.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("main0");
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("thread0");
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("thread1");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("uncomment the release line to make main1 get in");

        }).Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("main1");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

for more information have a look at http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore

Comment: Ok, but what about remaining 2 slots?

Comment: @maxim.tkachenko they can be used from other threads, I updated the answer and put a sample which shows how semaphores are thread-agnostic

Comment: Sorry, may be my answer is not clear. If I use "new  Semaphore(4, 6)" - only 4 threads can work at the same time? When other two will be available for threads?

Comment: you can change semaphore count between 0 and maximum value, so when you are setting maximum value to 6, and initial value to 4 it means your potential for concurrency is 6 but currently you offer 4 concurrent resources, if in some cases you decide that you want to increase concurrency you can call `Release` which will open another slot for you however you cannot exceed maximum value set for semaphore

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So can I think about other two slots like about "margin of safety" which could be released by semaphore in some special situation?

Comment: If you are using the semaphore for controlling concurrent resource allocation, then yes we can assume it as some kind of spare resources.

Answer (score 8):

I like [Albahari's explanation](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore):

> A semaphore is like a nightclub: it has a certain capacity, enforced by a bouncer. Once it’s full, no more people can enter, and a queue builds up outside. Then, for each person that leaves, one person enters from the head of the queue. The constructor requires a minimum of two arguments: the number of places currently available in the nightclub and the club’s total capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a mutex, a semaphore can Release() and WaitOne() in any thread.
WaitOne() — counter in Semaphore decrement. If counter == 0, blocks until it increases. 
Release() — counter in Semaphore increment. Second constructor parameter == counter,  blocks until it decreases.